Java concurrency - Multithreading
I'm new to Java concurrency and I'm trying to create the following program:
In an office there are 3 workers and 1 boss.

If the workers arrive to the office prior than the boss they
say "I've arrived" and go to sleep.
When the boss arrives they resume from sleep and start to work.
If they arrive after the boss they apologize and start to work.

I'm getting the output below. The desired output would be that the worker 0 starts to work once the boss has arrived, before the messages from Worker 2 and 1:

Worker 0 has arrived. ZZZZZ
BOSS: THE BOSS HAS ARRIVED
Worker 2: has arrived. Hi Boss, time to work
Worker 1: has arrived. Hi Boss, time to work
Worker 0 Eeeeh, TIME TO WORK!

I've created 3 classes for this project: Greeting.java, Worker.java, Main.java
I guess the issue is on Greeting.java. On the greetingWorker method, if the boss is not in the office the worker arrives and I send him to sleep/rest with the method wait() after printing his message. Once the boss arrives, from the method greetingBoss I resume or at least try to resume the Worker's thread from sleep with nofity(), but does not seem to be working, since messages from workers that were not at the office when he arrived are printing first.
public class Greeting extends Thread {
    private boolean bossArrived;
    
    public Greeting() {
        this.bossArrived = false;
        
        }
    
    public synchronized void greetingWorker(String name) {
        try {   
                if (!bossArrived) {
    
                System.out.println(name + " has arrived. ZZZZZ");
                
                wait();
                System.out.println(name + " Eeeeh, TIME TO WORK!");
    
                } 
                else {

                System.out.println(name + ": has arrived. Hi Boss, time to work");
                }
                
                }
            catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
        }

    public synchronized void greetingBoss(String name) {
        
        System.out.println(name + ": THE BOSS HAS ARRIVED");
        this.bossArrived = true;
        notifyAll();
    }
}

… and:
public class Worker extends Thread {
    String name;
    Greeting greeting;
    Boolean isBoss;
    
    public Worker(String name, Greeting hola, Boolean boss) {
        this.name = name;
        this.greeting = hola;
        this.isBoss = boss;
    }
    
    public void run() {
        if (isBoss) {
            greeting.greetingBoss(name);
        }
        else {
            greeting.greetingWorker(name);
        }
    }
}

… and:
import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;
import java.util.concurrent.Semaphore;

public class MainLlegaElJefe {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
        Greeting mySaludo = new Greeting();
        
        Worker Worker1 = new Worker("Worker 0", mySaludo, false);
        Worker Worker2 = new Worker("Worker 1", mySaludo, false);
        Worker Worker3 = new Worker("Worker 2", mySaludo, false);
        
        Worker theBoss = new Worker("BOSS", mySaludo, true);
        
        Worker1.start();
        Worker2.start();
        Worker3.start();
        
        theBoss.start();
    }
}

I've also tried the following modifying the greetingWorker method, which gives the desired output except when the Boss is the first arriving at the office. In that case only prints boss's greeting and the rest of workers never arrive:
if (!bossArrived) {
    
    System.out.println(name + " has arrived. ZZZZZ");
    
    wait();
    System.out.println(name + " Eeeeh, TIME TO WORK!");
    notifyAll();

} 
else {
    wait();
    System.out.println(name + ": has arrived. Hi Boss, time to work");
}

Does anyone have any suggestion?

Take more care when posting code here. Eliminate extra blank lines. Post each class separately.  Use none to format output. I fixed some of that for you this time. And, if you are going to put a blank line on the top of each method’s content, just put the curly brace there rather than at end of previous line. Tell your IDE which style you prefer, let it auto-format.

Vague title. Rewrite to summarize your specific technical issue.

What do you mean by sleep(wait())? That doesn't make sense to me and is not in the code shared. The threads are waiting, not sleeping that I can see.

@aled I chose the wrong words. I meant that I send the thread to wait/rest with the wait() method

they all have the same Greeting, and that thread is waiting until the boss arrives.  (when first worker greets Greeting is stuck waiting until notified... no notification happens until the boss arrives... greetingBoss method)

I guess it's the synchronized method that's actually waiting cuz greetingBoss can still be called.

It sounds like you want deterministic ordering, which means you must coordinate that yourself because threads are non-deterministic. Your problem is more of a queuing system, often where you might abstract away threads into the actual task. Since you want them to run in FIFO order before the next item, this sequential work defeats any benefit of having threads. But as a toy, I would use CompletableFuture as a start signal with each worker chained after the last (thenRunAsync) to make it execute in series.

Adding to what @BenManes said, you should not be expecting threads to execute in a particular order, even if started sequentially in the code. That's a common mistake in concurrent code, ie having incorrect expectations. Also note that all the threads are sharing the same system output. It may not be the most reliable way to observe the execution behavior of the threads.
